# Jquery animation moving all content in mobile viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery slider that slides the content up. I have used jquery to make it not run on a mobile device. However if the user resizes the browser screen to a mobile resolution the jquery will continue to run and infact move all of the content in my website up even when the slider itself is not there on the mobile version. Any idea?

Sorry I dont have a jsfiddle but everything is [here](https://belgium-child.codio.io/)

Comment: Are you using media queries? Sounds like you need to include "screen" if you are:  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px)

Comment: check the var height = 600 value on your slider. That's the whole viewport on mobile, I believe that might be the issue.

Comment: the var height is just to determine how far the slides travel up. and i am using media queries but the problem lies in the jQuery. If you check the website then resize until the css changes to mobile you will see the issue i am talking about :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because of this statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px)" src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

What you want is this "jQuery.js" should include for **viewport width > 480px but this is not right syntax**.

Also, **since you have used setInterval in jQuery.js, it keep calculating values and sliding keeps happening**.

I will suggest to do something like this use **orientationChange/resize** event.

After your comment:

Ideally, you should not keep executing setInterval and use clearInterval for mobile site. But, just as a fix, you can do this:

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 480){
     $slideContainer.animate({'margin-top': '-='+height}, animationSpeed, function() {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-top', 0);
                }
            });
          }
        }, pause);
```

Still I would like to say, **use resize/orientationChange event and clearInterval for width <=480. Again restart interval for width > 480**

Comment: the media part wasnt meant to still be there. Error still exists with it gone. I have a if statement for the width in the jquery. (if($(window).width() >= 481){ CODE}. But that doesnt stop upon resize to mobile. Is there a way to stop the code when the site changes to mobile css?

Comment: This does work great thanks. Only issue is that if the user resizes on a slide that isn't the first, the content is still moved on the mobile version depending on what slide it was when they resized. Anyway that it could be forced back to slide 1 for example ?

Comment: May be you should change your logic because the basic reason of continous sliding is setInterval only and when you resize take care to use clearInterval.